# Preciso checar se meu JSON está vazio para buscar url com parametro definido no curl

Tags: php, javascript, json, libcurl

```
function BuscaMarca(marca, modelo, anomodelo) {
    marca = $('#marca').val();
    tipo = $('#tipo').val();
    $.get("curl.php?tabela=BuscaMarca&marca=" + marca + "&tipo=" + tipo, function(data, status) {
        if (data == 0) {
            alert("Empty");
        } else {
            $('#marca').html(data);
            BuscaModelo(); //Busca o Modelo 
        }

    });
}
```

Eu preciso que algum jeito, marca e tipo estiverem vazios, tem que ficar tabela=BuscaMarca&marca=&tipo=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa validar as variáveis

```
tipo = $('#tipo').val();
if(tipo=="")tipo=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Faz um IF Ternário ao receber o valor do campo, perguntando se o conteúdo do valor é maior que 0. Se não for, é 0.

#### IF Ternário

```
VARIÁVEL = (CONDIÇÃO) ? VERDADEIRO : FALSO
```

#### Código

```
function BuscaMarca(marca, modelo, anomodelo) {

    marca = ($('#marca').val().length > 0) ? $('#marca').val() : 0;
    tipo  = ($('#tipo').val().length > 0) ? $('#tipo').val() : 0;

    $.get("curl.php?tabela=BuscaMarca&marca=" + marca + "&tipo=" + tipo, function(data, status) {
        if (data == 0) {
            alert("Empty");
        } else {
            $('#marca').html(data);
            BuscaModelo(); //Busca o Modelo 
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um condicional inline pra checar se estão vazios e atribuir os valores de acordo, segue o exemplo:

```
marca = ( $('#marca').val() != '' ? $('#marca').val() : '' );
```

Note: Ele faz uma checagem do valor de marca, se ele for diferente de vazio, ele executa o que vem depois da `?` que é o próprio valor, se não ele executa depois dos `:` que é o valor default que você especificar.

Dessa forma o tipo ficaria:

```
tipo = ( $('#tipo').val() != '' ? $('#tipo').val() : '0' );
```